# Revit API: How to get ElementID of created family instance?

Tags: c#, revit-api

Say I have created a FamilyInstance:

```
instance = myDocument.Create.NewFamilyInstance(base, symbol, level, StructuralType.Column);
```

How do I get the element id of the column I created above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Id property on the instance object returned.